# Probability of picking a specific number from 4 draws with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have 10 balls numbered $0$ through $9$. We will draw 4 balls, with replacement. I want to know the probability that a specific number (let's say 6) will appear at least once.

I've approached this in 2 different ways, but they give different results. First one involves calculating the probability that the number doesn't occur at all and subtracting from one.

$$P = 1 - \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^4 = 0.3439$$

Second one is calculating probability of drawing balls other than 6 and also one 6. The last term is the number of ways the 6 can be allocated among the draws.

$$P = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^1 \left(    \begin{matrix}
    4 \\
    1
    \end{matrix}\right) = 0.2916$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing the probability of drawing $6$ two, three or four times.

Comment: The first is the probability that $\textit {at least} $ one six is drawn, the second is the probability that $\textit {exactly}$ one six is drawn.

Comment: Obvious in retrospect, thank you.